# How to import a function with scalar return value in EF 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF 5 with .NET 4.5, I have created a model for my database and imported my functions in to the model, I can successfully import TVF an SP but I'm not able to import functions with scalar return value.
Is it possible with designer or I should manually edit the `edmx` file?

Comment: On top of my head I dont think you can do a function import for Scalar functions, need to manually edit the edmx.

Comment: @Nilesh thanks for your answer, can you tell me how should I do that

Comment: Just a thought; Can you create a stored proc and call the scalar function from within the SP? The other way would be to edit the edmx file in a text editor. you can follow this [link](http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/first-impressions-of-database-first-development-with-entity-framework-5-in-visual-studio-2012/) for an example.

Comment: Hi @BigBoss I have added a new answer please check, it should work. No other solution work at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scroll down to the section on Scalar Valued Functions on this page:

[Database First Development with Entity Framework 5 - Importing Scalar Valued Functions](http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/first-impressions-of-database-first-development-with-entity-framework-5-in-visual-studio-2012/)

You can either follow this ugly workaround, or you can follow the advice that I will give at the very bottom of this answer.

Here's an excerpt from that article (on the workaround):

> "This method requires some minor changes of the .edmx file’s xml,
>   directly. To do so, right-click on the .edmx file and select ‘Open
>   With…’, ‘XML (Text) Editor’. This is how the functions looks in the
>   .edmx file before changes:

```
<Function Name="CountActivities" ReturnType="int" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
    <Parameter Name="personId" Type="int" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="CountHydrations" ReturnType="int" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
    <Parameter Name="personId" Type="int" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="CountMeals" ReturnType="int" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
    <Parameter Name="personId" Type="int" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

> "Remove the ‘ReturnType’ attribute from the  element. Then,
>   add a  element to each of the  elements.
>   See the modified .edmx file below for the contents of the  elements.

```
<Function Name="CountActivities" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
    <CommandText>
        SELECT [dbo].[CountActivities] (@personId)
    </CommandText>
    <Parameter Name="personId" Type="int" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="CountHydrations" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
    <CommandText>
        SELECT [dbo].[CountHydrations] (@personId)
    </CommandText>
    <Parameter Name="personId" Type="int" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="CountMeals" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
    <CommandText>
        SELECT [dbo].[CountMeals] (@personId)
    </CommandText>
    <Parameter Name="personId" Type="int" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

> "Next, in the Model Browser, right-click on the ‘Function Imports’
>   folder and select ‘Add Function Import…’ This brings up the ‘Add
>   Function Import’ dialog window. We will import the ‘CountActivities’
>   scalar-valued function to show this method. Enter the following
>   information in the dialog window and select Save."

**My Advice:**
Considering the effort required, it is way easier to **just create a table-valued function** that only returns one row to achieve the same effect and purpose.

Here's an example of a User-Defined Table-Valued function in SQL Server:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetTotalMinutesInvoiced] ( @billingType INT )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    (
      SELECT
            SUM([ProgressNote].[TotalMinutes]) AS 'TotalMinutesInvoiced'
        FROM
            [dbo].[InvoiceEntry]
        JOIN [dbo].[ProgressNote]
            ON [ProgressNote].[ProgressNoteID] = [InvoiceEntry].[ProgressNoteID]
        WHERE
            [InvoiceEntry].[BillingTypeID] = @billingType
            AND progressNote.[IsRecordedInInvoiceEntry] = 1
    )
GO
```

Notice also that you can actually call scalar-valued user-defined functions from within your table-valued function.

To call the table valued function, you would probably want to use the FirstOrDefault method like this:

```
        private void UpdateStatisticsPanel()
        {
            var billingTypeId = int.Parse(txtBillingTypeId.Text);

            var totalMinutesInvoiced = context.udfGetTotalMinutesInvoiced(billingType: billingTypeId);
            var minutesInvoiced = totalMinutesInvoiced.FirstOrDefault();
            var invoiced = new Tuple<string, int?>("totalMinutesInvoiced:", minutesInvoiced);
            lstFinancialSummary.Items.Add(invoiced);

            var totalMinutesNotInvoiced = context.udfGetTotalMinutesNotInvoiced(billingType: billingTypeId);
            var minutesNotInvoiced = totalMinutesNotInvoiced.FirstOrDefault();
            var notInvoiced = new Tuple<string, int?>("totalMinutesNotInvoiced:", minutesNotInvoiced);

            lstFinancialSummary.Items.Add(notInvoiced);
            // remember to push the values up to the ListView.
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Struggling with the same problem for almost a day and with all due respect @devinbost, it didn't solve the problem but it put me closer to the solution. In conclusion, the one and only solution are to convert the function scalar type to table value type with a single value in the table, please see the code sample.

**You don't have to change anything in the EDMX XML, please modify the SQL function**

> Scalar function as it was, which doesn't work

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSha256]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @str nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS VARBINARY(32)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ( SELECT * FROM HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @str) AS HASH256 );
END -- this doesn't work.
```

> Scalar function -> Converted to Table Valued function , it works

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSha2561]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @str nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS  @returnList TABLE (CODE varbinary(32))
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @returnList
    SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @str);

    RETURN; -- This one works like a charm.

END
```

Edmx screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't retrieve return parameter from a stored procedure, 
so I used context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand instead of "SqlQuery" when calling  the stored and it works. Hope this suggestion could help someone.